# Javascript: Solicitar numero con prompt, si es distinto a 0 duplicar y mostrar alert, si es igual a 0 evitar bucle

Tags: javascript

Pongo el siguiente código, me ejecuta solo una vuelta

```
numero = prompt("Escribe un número") 
var multiplica = numero * 2; 

while (numero != "0") { 
    alert (numero*2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que poner el prompt dentro del while asi:

```js
var numero;

while (numero != "0"){ 
    numero = prompt("Escribe un número") 
    if (numero == 0) {
      alert("Gracias");
    } else {
      var multiplica = numero * 2; 
      alert (numero*2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Y si quiero que al colocar 0 aparezca un alert pero no multiplicando sino con una frase?

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.